# Input Value HW for Python

Tags: python

i have to create an input, square it and give back a reciprocal of the number.. Help!!
    prompts the user for an input value
    prints the reciprocal value on one line
    prints the square of value on a second line
    labels the values with a descriptor

So far I have

```
def main (): 
    print("this program sqaures your original number and gives back the reciprocal number") 
    print () 
    x=eval(input("Please enter a number"))
```

Comment: This is what I have so far:

Comment: def main ():
 print("this program sqaures your original number and gives back the reciprocal number")
 print ()
 x=eval(input("Please enter a number"))

Comment: You don't have Anything so far! and folks here don't help with homework problems, until you ask a specific question about an issue you are running into :)

Comment: You have 3 sub tasks here 1) take the input 2) square the number 3) return the reciprocal of that number. Which of those are you stuck on?

Comment: K man, I just need help on how to print a reciprocal value.

Comment: ill figure it out :)

Comment: if x is the input, you can set `xx=x*x`. From here, return the reciprocal as `1/xx`

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to `eval()` or `exec()` user input. It's also a good idea to check that the input is actually a number of some sort. You want to square the input by multiplying it by itself, then return 1 over that squared number. If you're doing this for homework: Shame on you.

```
def main (): 
    print("this program sqaures your original number and gives back the reciprocal number") 
    print () 
    x = input("Please enter a number")
    assert isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float)  # make sure its a number
    xx = x*x  # square the user input
    return 1/xx
```

Comment: I'm a beginner man, there should be no shaming, and its something that I'm trying to better understand man. You don't have to say that.

Comment: @John I hear you. I'm hoping that you're learning as much as you could be, without giving up before trying a few things. I didn't down-vote your post, as is recommended with posts lacking coherence or steps, because I'm giving you the benefit of the doubt that you're trying to understand the solution. Good luck with it

Comment: @JacobIRR if you feel the question is unworthy of an answer then don't answer it. At the end of the day most users refuse to answer such questions to encourage the OP to avoid shortcuts in their learning that are detrimental to their long term progress.

Comment: Thanks man. I just had a big brain fart and really needed much needed clearing up, this is my first time coding and first time on this site. I hope to learn more in class, and from much more experienced coders like you . I hear you,  and thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @PaulRooney - I'm having a hard time gauging what I consider worthy... If it is utterly incoherent (like this gem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43360575/using-xgboost-to-predict-the-outcomes-who-can-help-me-i-will-give-you-data-ca), I downvote, but this one felt gray to me.